# JQuery alternative to classic for-loop if not collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I want to loop over something that is not a collection I may use a for-loop in JavaScript. So to alert day numbers 0-9:

```
var days = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < days; i++)
   alert(i);
```

But what would be the JQuery way of doing such a for-loop (assuming I can't use $each, as it's not a collection)?

Comment: If plain javascript works, why not use that?

Comment: Because usually it can be done more compact in JQuery.

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex The only thing I could think of is readability I guess. But this is the way to do it

Comment: It's not really more compact in jQuery, as a matter of fact the `for` loop is much quicker. It is OK to mix jQuery and JavaScript syntax where it makes sense @brinch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery.each works just fine

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
    alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

But honestly, vanilla JavaScript is much better for what you seem to be asking

Comment: +1 for recognizing that vanilla JS is the better way to go on this.

Answer (score 4):

<s>It is bad, but...</s>
**$.each** way:

```
var days = 10;
$.each(new Array(days), function(i, _) {
    alert(i);
});
```

**for** keyword way:

```
(function(iter) {
    for (var i = 0; i < days; ++i) {
        iter(i);
    }
})(function(i) {
    alert(i);
});
```

Custom jQuery plugin [$.loop](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/p30o0wn0/) way:

```
;(function($) {
    $.loop = function(num, iter) {
        for (var i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
            iter(i);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage of **$.loop** in your case:

```
var days = 10;
$.loop(days, function(i) {
    alert(i);
});
```

[Performance test](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/fokq10kj/) says that **$.each** is slower than other, but for solving 99% of problems it is no matter.

Single-line way in your case is:

```
$.loop(days, alert);
```

Or:

```
$.each(new Array(days), alert);
```

Comment: Because you need to create new Array. What if `days` would be 1000000?

Comment: That would be lengthy in a for loop too - but the for loop would be more efficient.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I made the simple performance test http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/fokq10kj/2/ =)

Comment: You should use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. And someone made a good performance test [here](http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-jquery-each-vs-for-loop)

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I updated the test http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/fokq10kj/3/ for greater convenience. And we can see that the browser (Chrome in my case) doesn't optimize `for` loop unfortunately. :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63193/discussion-between-dizel3d-and-jay-blanchard).